# How to write a string with " in the middle in Groovy

Tags: groovy

How can you write `hfjfhbj"v\hbfjh` in Groovy string. I have tried escaping the character with with `hfjfhbj|"v\hbfjh` and `hfjfhbj\\"v\hbfjh` and still its not working.

Comment: What quotes are you using around the string? where do you enter the string (file, somewhere else, ...). Please provide the exact error and how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy has a few ways to do this. You just have to choose which quotes to use based on the string type you intend to create.

Using a GString, escape `"` and `\`: `"hfjfhbj\"v\\hbfjh"`

Using a String, escape `\`: `'hfjfhbj"v\\hbfjh'`

Using a multi-line GString: `"""hfjfhbj"v\\hbfjh"""`

In all cases, you have to escape the backslash. You have to escape `"` with a backslash if you quote your text using `""`. In other cases (multi-line GString - `"""..."""` - or simple String - `'...'` - or multi-line String - `'...'` - you can use `"`) unescaped